# Select percentile rank from table based on score SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains what score equates to what percentile rank.  This is a snippet from said table to give you an idea of structure:

```
dateStart   dateEnd     category    score   percentileRank
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   81.5    97.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   80.7    96.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   80.0    95.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   79.5    94.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   79.0    93.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   78.6    92.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   78.1    91.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   77.8    90.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   77.6    89.0
2014-10-01  2014-12-31  category1   77.3    88.0
...         ...         ...         ...     ...
```

How do I `SELECT` the `percentileRank` based on a given `score`?  For example, if the score was 81, it should tell me that the percentile rank was 96.  Since the score can be any decimal value, I need to account for the ranges of a given percentile rank.  As such, I'm having a bit of trouble working out the conditions for this in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, a `top` or `max` query will give you the closest match down from your input:

```
select top 1 percentileRank
from tbl
where score <= @score
order by score desc;

select max(percentileRank)
from tbl
where score <= @score;
```

Comment: That sqlfiddle seems to be acting funky.  I'm getting off-by-one responses in the `top 1` solution, and I got a response of 88th percentile for an input of 77.9 (it should be 90th percentile)

Comment: The fiddle incorrectly defined the score column, leaving out the decimal point info. Assuming your column is defined with decimal places, you'll be good. The sqlfiddle site isn't cooperating with me right now, otherwise I'd edit it.

Comment: On an efficiency note, is either query better/faster performance wise?  I realize this is a trivial example, but I always like to learn where code can be improved.

Comment: updated sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7ff8/2, was an issue with sql fiddle not detecting type correctly.

Comment: Looks like `max` would be more efficient. I'm not very good at reading execution plans, but the numbers are smaller for that one. Plus it makes sense since it wouldn't actually need to sort, just keep tabs on the largest value while scanning the table. If there were indexes there, it might make a difference, but I don't know.

Comment: The upside of `top` over `max` of course would be if you cared about other columns in that table instead of just the percentileRank column - you could easily add those columns to the query without changing anything else.